# How to highlight polygons within another polygon?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, polygon, symbology

I want to symbolize public buildings in OSM data.

For Example: There is a polygon and in column "amenity" it has the value "school". But i don't want to highlight this polygon, but the buildings inside this polygon.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the "school" polygons and the "building" polygons are in the same layer?  If so, I would approach this by creating a temporary layer of school polygons with a Query.  Then save this layer as something else, like school.shp.  Use the Spatial Query plugin to find "building" polygons in your original layer that are Within your "school" polygons.  You can then save these as a new layer or give them an attribute you can use to highlight with a different style.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential possibilities:

a) schools are an attribute within a polygon just like "daycare" or "church" would be an attribute within the buildings polygon layer. In this instance you select by attributes within the table view would allow you to select all "Schools" or whatever you choice.

b) Might seem basic but I often get asked "why do the multiple polygons get selected when I try to click on one building". This often happens because multiple layers are available to be selected for a single given geographical point. Under the table of contents you can turn off layers in order to avoid selecting them.

Comment: Or do you mean you want to select all polygons of one type, that fall within another polygon? If so, then you should use select by location rather than attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try layer properties --> style and select "rulebased"

There you have to define a rule but I do not know what this rule should look like.